# Расширить/сузить четырехугольник

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Даны 4 точки выпуклого четырёхугольника. Как пропорционально расширить/сузить его относительно центра тяжести?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

1. Найти центр тяжести.
2. Провести из него лучи к вершинам.
3. На лучах найти точки удаленные от центра тяжести в нужной пропорции относительно старых вершин.

Answer (score 3):

"Пропорционально расширить/сузить", по-видимому, подразумевает преобразование гомотетии с центром в "центре тяжести" и коэффициентом `K`.

Соответственно, надо сначала вычислить координаты центра тяжести `(xC, yC)`, а затем каждую вершину `(x, y)` исходного многоугольника пересчитать как

```
x = (x - xC) * K + xC
y = (y - yC) * K + yC
```

Правда непонятно, зачем нам тут 1) выпуклость четырехугольника и 2) четырехугольность четырехугольника. Решение никак не использует ни выпуклости, ни количества вершин.